# using operator & after class method name

Tags: c++

I found the C++ class with API like this:

```
class foo
{
.....
public:
int& func1() & ;
int func1() && ;
.....
}
```

what does operator **&** and **&&** do after the method name and what is the difference between these two function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called *"ref qualifiers"* and allow you to overload a member function depending on the value category of `*this`.

- `int& func1() &` means: this overload of `func1` can be invoked on any instance of `*this` which can be bound to an *lvalue reference*.
- `int func1() &&` means: this overload of `func1` can be invoked on any instance of `*this` which can be bound to an *rvalue reference*.

E.g.

```
foo f; f.func1(); // calls &-qualified version
foo{}.func1();    // calls &&-qualified version
```